# Taking hold of file and locking it from being used

Tags: java, locking

I have a program where when I start it up, it will create a file within a specific folder.

I am trying to recreate an issue that was brought to my attention recently, but I am struggling to do so.

What I need to do: Once the program creates a file, I need to take hold of that file (from another program) and prevent it from being accessed. I need to hold it for a minute or two, and then i can release it. I created a small stand alone project to try and grab/lock this folder, but it does not seem to work because my other main project can still access/ manipulate this file.

```
public class TestOpenFile {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {


        Path faxFolder = Paths.get("D:/main/TEST/");
        WatchService watchService = FileSystems.getDefault().newWatchService();
        faxFolder.register(watchService, StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE);

        boolean valid = true;
        do {
            WatchKey watchKey = watchService.take();

            for (WatchEvent event : watchKey.pollEvents()) {
                WatchEvent.Kind kind = event.kind();
                if (StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE.equals(event.kind())) {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(100);
                        Path path = Paths.get("D:/main/TEST/TEST.run");
                        FileChannel channel = FileChannel.open(path, StandardOpenOption.WRITE,StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
                        FileLock lock = channel.lock(); 
                        System.out.println("SLEEP"); 
                        Thread.sleep(60000);
                        System.out.println("WAKE UP"); 
                        lock.release();
                        channel.close();
                    }
                    catch (IOException e) {
                        System.out.println("I/O Error: " + e.getMessage());

                    }
                    String fileName = event.context().toString();
                    System.out.println("File Created:" + fileName);
                }
            }
            valid = watchKey.reset();

        } while (valid);

    }
}
```

Sp currently I start running TestOpenFile.java and it sits there and waits for events in the TEST directory. I then start up my other project, and that project will drop the TEST.run file in the directory. In TestOpenFile.java I want to then grab that file lock it and wait there for a minute.

Currently, I can see that the "SLEEP" print statement is hut, but then the TEST.run file is renamed by my other project to TEST.done which I am trying to delay)

Am I missing something here?I have tried reading multiple posts on stack and online but nothing has helped me out yet.

Comment: Which operating system? On Linux you can't actually lock a file except cooperatively (that is, all the applications that access it agree to abide by the lock).

Comment: And you can delete it at any time because that doesn't require you to open it, and doesn't interfere with processes which have it open.

Comment: I think the easiest way to do so is by creating another file that is actually a lock file. If you don't know the mechanism I can be more specific and answer the question.

Comment: yeah, that sounds like a good idea

Comment: i edited my post. its not actually deleting the file but rather editing it to have a different extension. And this is on windows.